# Errors in the OLAP storage engine: A duplicate attribute key has been found when processing: Table

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I have gone through so many articles on this but was not able to find the exact solution.

First I swapped all NULL with ISNULL and again after that I'm getting same error:

> Errors in the OLAP storage engine: A duplicate attribute key has been found when processing: Table: 'dbo_LoyaltyProfileMaster', Column: 'ReferreCode', Value: 'EST000001'. The attribute is 'Referre Code'.

If I delete this particular data then its runs fine.

**But as per my requirement I can get duplicates in this column**.

As this is not a primary key, I thought it should run fine.

Please let me know if you want to see the SQL Code for this.

Comment: What is the datatype of ReferreCode in the underlying data structure?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the column `ReferreCode` contains value 0 (zero) and value NULL. You should explicitly convert the NULL value to a non-null value defining a named query over your real database structure; so if your database table is `dbo_LoyaltyProfileMaster`, you should replace this table in the data source view with a named query, the definition of which should be something like:

```
SELECT 
    <field list of fields not including ReferreCode>
  , COALESCE(ReferreCode, 0) as ReferreCode 
FROM dbo_LoyaltyProfileMaster
```

You can map NULLs to a different value (not necessarily 0) if you wish.

And you must make sure to include this value in the dimension data source view object as well, perhaps defining a view or a named query as well.

Comment: I did this and it did not work. Also tried the cases in 
http://ms-olap.blogspot.pt/2009/11/duplicate-attribute-key-has-been-found.html
:/

Answer (score 0):

Go to your dimension properties -> Error Configuration -> keyDuplicate then change the value of key duplicate from reportAndStop to IgnoreError
Good luck